# Get x:Name from DependencyObject defined in XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I'm trying to get the `x:Name` of a DataGridColumn. The DataGridColumn is derived directly from DependencyObject, so I can't convert it to a `FrameworkElement` and use the `Name` property.

Here is my code in XAML:

```
<toolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Abgerechnet" x:Name="DataGridColumAbgerechnet" />
```

And now I want to find this Column in the DataGrid by its `x:Name`.

How can I do this?

Comment: where are you trying to use it, in xaml.cs it should be directly available when you do this.DataGridColumAbgerechnet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Attached Property from Non-DependencyObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483515/reading-attached-property-from-non-dependencyobject)

Comment: I have a function wich gets the DataGrid as DependencyObject, but not in the xaml.cs-file.

Answer (score 1):

`var column = (DataGridColumn)gridInstanceName.FindName("ColumnName");`

Should get you your column.